# Dynamic 365 Reports Get Error After Update to V8.2.19

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

i use dynamic 365 and my previous version was 8.2.5 and i installed V 8.2.19 directly both server and SRS  after installation finished none of reports works and only get exception as i attach.

is it because of update? or i have to check some where else?
[image]

also i found this on  report log file:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException,System.Web.UI.ViewStateException,System.OutOfMemoryException,System.Web.HttpException,System.IO.IOException,System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException

Comment: As you're using an OnPrem version you should be able to get the SSRS error log (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources?view=sql-server-ver15). Please update the answer with it and we'll try to help you.

Comment: I Updated Question With Log file problem